# How to create an installer out of an installer?

Tags: installation, nsis

I have an old legacy application around for which I only have the installer. it doesn't do anything more than uncompress and register itself and his library's.

As i don't have the source-code it gives me a lot of headaches in maintenance problems. In some particular computers (Acer Aspire One with Windows) just do not run.

I would like to extract the files and re-create this installer with NSIS. Is this possible or I'm nuts?

The original installer has been created with Ghost Installer Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to find a machine that it **does** run on, and then install some "install guard" software (often called things like Acme Uninstaller). Use this to track what actually gets installed and then copy the relevant files and write your own.

It looks like a lot of hassle to me, and you may be on thin ice with regards to the licence.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a program that monitors new files being installed and then get the files that were installed from their respective paths.

For instance, I [found this](http://www.tucows.com/preview/222221) in about 10 seconds with Google, there are more programs like it, but I am inexperienced with those available for Windows.

Comment: An installer can do more than drop files; for example it may evan have conditional behavior based on which system it's running on.  I'd assume the OP wants to maintain any MSMs or custom actions that the original installer performed.

Comment: Well, he did ask how to "extract the files" from it ;)

Comment: Hi, well there might be problems like the case that the installer selects some libraries to install in some system and not in others.

I'm aware of that but if can't get the original packaging script, I'll just go the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If it uses a MSI file, you can use Orca or SuperOrca to get at the stuff packed inside.

Comment: Hi, No it isn't a MSI file is a exe create with Ghost Installer Studio (a demo actually, so the original packager didn't have much respect for licenses either).

Answer (score 0):

This is typically the job of *Repackaging Software*. There are a few ways such tools work but typically it is by taking a look at a system before and after you install it on a clean system and building a custom installer from the detected changes. This is normally done to generate a customized installation and/or one that can be automated in its deployment. I'm not aware of one that generates an NSIS package, the standard format today is MSI (Windows Installer).

If you have the original installer any repackager will do, but even without the original setup program you can do as some of the others here suggest and monitor the use of the application for its requirements. The two most popular repackaging tools are InstallShield AdminStudio and Wise Package Studio. The feature may also be part of a setup authoring solution, so check with your in-house developers if you can.

A full list of repackaging tools can be found [here at AppDeploy.com](http://www.appdeploy.com/tools/browse.asp?startnum=1&catmatch=2014&sortby=TotalScore)

One free repackaging tool available for creating Windows Installer setups from another [legacy] setup tool (with which I must divulge I'm involved) is the [AppDeploy Repackager](http://www.appdeploy.com/tools/repackager). Another free repackager is WinINSTALL LE.