# How to create an installer out of an installer in Java EnvironMent

Tags: java

i must created an exe with another Exe. While the first Exe has some restrictions, in the second exe which follows that restrictions. i use Innosetup and Launch4j for creating the first exe and i don't know how to develop an exe while i am execute another exe, is it possible in java environment.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  Are you trying to build an installer that performs the same functions that the first installer does?  In that case see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234934/how-to-create-an-installer-out-of-an-installer).

Comment: Not at all Kyle the second exe is my source while i intstall it an out put for example like "HelloWorld", the purpose of first exe is to encapsulate the second exe.

Comment: Why the heck are you even using Java to develop something that will obviously only run on Windows?